# PHP framework for quickly building an interface based on DB relations

Tags: php, orm, frameworks

I have a simple database:

```
FilmStudios
FilmStudio-DVDs
DVDs
Actors
Actors-DVDs
DVD-Scenes
```

A few more tables... I'd like to know if there is a PHP framework that I could just input the db relationships into, and get a quick and dirty interface for browsing the information...

Ideally, it would spit out code that I could then massage into a more finished product.

Comment: phpmyadmin? not really sure what you are asking. are you sure its a framework you want?

Comment: Maybe you are asking about ORM? Take a look at Propel or Doctrine

Comment: Most frameworks that support code generation should allow you to do this. CakePHP works pretty much exactly as described.

Comment: Yes, a php code generator based on the schema is exactly what I'm looking for... Checking out CakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical frameworks are not very good at managing User Interface and focus primarily on the back-end / MVC part. You should look for **Web User Interface Framework**.

Here is a sample of what might achieve in [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/) with minimum coding:

[image]

There is also a Model Generator add-on and many other enhancements. For as start, you will be fine using "Tabs" and "CRUD".

http://agiletoolkit.org/a/schemagenerator/how

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need a framework, you can do what you describe using an ORM, but I have included frameworks for the sake of completeness:

ORMs:

- [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) (my personal preference)
- [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/)

Frameworks:

- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/what-is-symfony)
- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)

There are several more frameworks, which will bubble to the top of a google search on 'php frameworks', the above listed are the major players.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Codigniter](http://codeigniter.com/).

It won't do everything for you, but it makes it a lot easier.

Have a look at their [example video](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/) for a start, and move on to what you need to do from there.